# Set wallpaper & return to DEFAULT home screen

Tags: wallpaper

After choosing & setting a wallpaper I would like to return to the DEFAULT home screen (i.e. pg 2 of 3) so the user can immediately see the new wallpaper.

Intent intent2 = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
   intent2.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
   intent2.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
   startActivity(intent2);

The above works fine, but returns to the last home page used, not necessarily the DEFAULT homepage. Is there an EXTRA or FLAG I can use to accomplish this?

Comment: You probably want to mention in the tags the operating system, that you are talking about, so your question gets highlighted for the experts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer... use TWO intents!

```
                    Intent intent2 = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
                    intent2.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
                    intent2.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    startActivity(intent2);

                    Intent intent3 = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
                    intent3.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
                    intent3.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    startActivity(intent3);
```